# Cannot generate short GUID that passes complex regular expression

Tags: c#

Our system sends data using a GUID as a unique identifier

Changing this approach would be complex

Now we have an annoying issue where the system we are integrating only allows unique identifiers that are 35 or less characters

They perform a complex regular expression validation on the id we provide them

^\w+$

I am not an expert on regular expressions so this doesnt really make much sense to me

How can I get round this?

Generating a GUID and removing the slashes as this fails the regular expression

Converting the GUID to base 64 is also not an option

Paul

Comment: Do you want to generate GUID without slashes?

Comment: "Generating a GUID and removing the slashes as this fails" -- how so? It seems to work here: https://regexfiddler.com/e/z4cjwiljn6gj

Comment: @Xerillio We can generate a GUID and  format to remove slashes.  var guid = new Guid();   var formatedId = guid.ToString("N");  The formatted string is still a valid GUID with 32 chars. So it will pass the regex scenario

Comment: Thanks that works, I had extra characters in my expression.  Please add answer then I can tick it for others as this is far simpler than a lot of the other shorten GUID solutions